# Optimizar BackTracking

Tags: java, algoritmos, optimización

estoy intentando optimizar este algoritmo backtracking que me tarda 400ms en ejecutarse.

¿Alguna recomendación para mejorar tiempo de ejecución de este algoritmo?

**Test:**

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args){

    BackTracking a = new BackTracking();
    List b = a.recursividad(0,new ArrayList(),new TreeSet(),new TreeSet());
    System.out.println("Soluciones: "+b.size());
    for(List c : b){
        System.out.println(c);
    }

}
}
```

**Reinas:**

```
public class Reina {
private Integer y;
private Integer x;

public Reina(int x, int y) {       
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public Integer getY() {
    return y;
}
public Integer getX() {
    return x;
}

public Integer getDiagonalPrincipal(){
    return y-x;
}
public Integer getDiagonalSecundaria(){
    return y+x;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "[" + x + ","+ y + "]";
}

}
```

**BackTracking:**

```
public class BackTracking {

public Integer reinas = 4;
private List> resultado = new ArrayList>();
public List> recursividad(Integer x,List yOcupadas,Set diagonalesPrincipalesOcupadas,Set diagonalesSecundariasOcupadas){

    if(x == reinas){

        //Posibles soluciones
        List lista = new ArrayList(); //Creo una lista con las posiciones actuales
        for(int i=0;i<"reinas";i++){
            lista.add(new Reina(i, yOcupadas.get(i)));
        }
        if(getNumeroDeConflictos(lista) == 0){ //Compruebo si esa lista es valida
            Integer i = 0;
            if(!resultado.containsAll(lista)){ //Si no esta en la solucion la lista, la a�ado
                    resultado.add(i, lista);
                    i++;
                }
            }

        }else{
            for(Integer a : getAlternativa(x,yOcupadas,diagonalesPrincipalesOcupadas,diagonalesSecundariasOcupadas)){ //Las alternativas

                yOcupadas.add(a);
                calculaPropiedadesDerivadas(yOcupadas,diagonalesPrincipalesOcupadas,diagonalesSecundariasOcupadas);
            
                recursividad(x+1, yOcupadas,diagonalesPrincipalesOcupadas,diagonalesSecundariasOcupadas);
            
                yOcupadas.remove(yOcupadas.size()-1);
                calculaPropiedadesDerivadas(yOcupadas,diagonalesPrincipalesOcupadas,diagonalesSecundariasOcupadas);
        }
    }
    return resultado;

}

private void calculaPropiedadesDerivadas(List yOcupadas,Set diagonalesPrincipalesOcupadas,Set diagonalesSecundariasOcupadas){
    diagonalesPrincipalesOcupadas = new HashSet<>();
    diagonalesSecundariasOcupadas = new HashSet<>();
    for(int x=0; x < yOcupadas.size();x++){
        diagonalesPrincipalesOcupadas.add(yOcupadas.get(x)-x);
        diagonalesSecundariasOcupadas.add(yOcupadas.get(x)+x);
    }
}

public List getAlternativa(Integer x,List yOcupadas,Set diagonalesPrincipalesOcupadas,Set diagonalesSecundariasOcupadas){
    Stream s = IntStream
            .range(0, reinas)
            .filter(y -> !yOcupadas.contains(y)
                    && !diagonalesPrincipalesOcupadas.contains(y-x)
                    && !diagonalesSecundariasOcupadas.contains(y+x)
                    )
            .boxed();
    return s.collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public Integer getNumeroDeConflictos(List ls){
    Set diagonalesPrincipalesOcupadas = new HashSet<>();
    Set diagonalesSecundariasOcupadas = new HashSet<>();
    for(Reina r:ls){
        diagonalesPrincipalesOcupadas.add(r.getY()-r.getX());
        diagonalesSecundariasOcupadas.add(r.getY()+r.getX());
    }
    return 2*reinas 
            - diagonalesPrincipalesOcupadas.size()
            -diagonalesSecundariasOcupadas.size();
}

}
```

Comment: no se que es un treeset, ni un hashset, ni los colectors ni los streams.. pero seguro que si lo haces con 2 vectores va a andar mucho mas rapido...

Comment: @gbianchi treeset y hashset es una colección, como si fuese una lista pero sin indice. Stream es en java8. Si no entiendes parte del código puede explicártelo. Voy a probarlo con array

Comment: no no.. lo que digo es que todo objeto tiene un overhead que en este caso suena a demasiado e innecesario.. no se cuanto tiempo le podras ganar.. pero seguro algo...

Comment: Seria conveniente que expliques y/o comentes en el codigo que se supone que estamos calculando/optimizando...

Comment: Tambien convendria que formatees y revises  el codigo, hay muchos errores, ni siquiera compila.

Comment: @leonbloy no compila? Que errores te da. El problema es el de las x reinas